# MySQL SUM longtext field with $1.000.00 as 1000

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a column `meta_entry` of type `longtext` with two entries in it `$1.000.00` and `$54.00`
When I run `SUM(SUBSTRING(meta_value, 2))` I get `55` because it doesn't read the first entry as `1000` rather it reads it as `1` because of the `.` after the `1`
How can i write a query that will ignore the periods, while still keeping the period at the end of the number (before the cents)?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as text if you need to be able to do math with them? Why aren't you using a numeric data type instead? Using the wrong data type causes this sort of problem. Use the proper type for the data, and format it as needed for display, and your life will be much easier.

Comment: Ken - I'm using WordPress and that's how it stores the data :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
mysql> select * from stuff;
+------------+
| meta_entry |
+------------+
| $1.000.00  |
| $54.00     |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following query yields:

```
mysql> select sum(replace(substring(meta_entry, 2), '.', '')) / 100 from stuff;
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| sum(replace(substring(meta_entry, 2), '.', '')) / 100 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  1054 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Of course you'll need a bit more if you have to have those cents on the end, in which case this big ole long ugly thing would do what you need:

```
mysql> select format(cast(sum(replace(substring(meta_entry, 2), '.', '')) as decimal) / 100, 2) as sum from stuff;
+----------+
| sum      |
+----------+
| 1,054.00 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: worked, tysm! at first it didn't work but then I realized that even tough mysql was showing `$1.000.00` it was really `$1,000.00` so all I had to do was   `sum(REPLACE(substring(meta_value,2),',',''))` and I still get to keep my two decimals at the end.